# Command-line tool to deduplicate a single humongous file?

Tags: windows

I make regular snapshots of my VM using a nightly script. These backups are compressed using WinRAR and do shrink considerably, but I suspect it's not as efficient as had the file had been deduplicated first (just a hunch which I'm hoping to test).

So instead of compressing the VHD itself, I would like to deduplicate the single file first, and then compress the output of the deduplicator.

Is anyone aware of such a CLI tool?

Comment: How do you mean to deduplicate 1 file?  Can you explain?

Comment: @Notitze by removing sections of the file that repeat. You might call this poor man's compression (which remove redundancy in general), but for files that have massive amounts of repetition a general-purpose compressor might not remove as much information as a deduplicator might.

Comment: I doubt that to be the case, really. The point of a compression tool is to eliminate duplication in a file, and trades off execution time in favor of compression ratio compared to a deduping fs. If the VM contains lots of empty space, zeroing out the free space from in the VM and compacting the virtual disk will probably help more than anything else.

Comment: @afrazier the empty space is of course zeroed and the disk gets compacted. I am yet to find a production quality free deduping FS for Windows. Existing compressors like WinRAR are pretty bad at handling long-range duplication. Try it yourself: make 10 copies of the same 5MB mp3 file, and compress at max settings using WinRAR. You will get a 50MB file, alas.

Comment: That's because WinRAR stores mp3  files by default. I'm on my phone right now, but try that with another type of file that does compress at last a little bit.

Comment: @afrazier ok, compressed a single 5MB DLL: shrunk to 25% of original size. Compressed 10 copies of the same DLL: shurnk to 24% of original size, i.e. 12 MB. WinRAR fails at deduplication big time, and it's fair enough - it's target users don't have this type of exact duplication in their typical data.

Comment: @romkyns One thing I forgot: looking for duplication across files requires solid mode, which rar doesn't use by default.  Turn that on and your results will be different.  As a quick test, a 3.5 MB file rar-ed down to 3.0 MB.  10 copies in a single rar were 30 MB.  10 copies in a solid RAR: 3.0 MB.  7-zip does solid mode by default.

Comment: That said, solid mode is of little use for compressing VHDs.  7-Zip might also fare better because it can use much larger dictionary sizes than rar can, which would help with compressing large amounts of data.

Comment: @afrazier curious, I had my solid mode enabled too. I suspect it depends on the size of the file being compressed - too large and it can no longer dedup efficiently. Anyway, I think we should take this chat somewhere else :) 7zip does indeed win at compressing the files at Ultra, but I only have a 4 hour window to compress the VHD at night, and within that time 7z compresses worse.

Comment: @romkyns That might have been because my file size was within the dictionary size.  Duh me.  :-)  Perhaps try making a shadow copy of the VHD (suspend VM, snapshot, restart VM) and back that up -- that'd let you extend your backup window and reduce downtime.  [Adi Oltean's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/) has some useful scripts and information on getting it done.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [OpenDedup's SDFS](http://www.opendedup.org/).  It's not exactly what you're looking for, but probably as close as you'll get with Windows.